Define emit with members?
In vue3 composition API, how do you define emits with members?
Example
<MyComponent @someEvent.customMember="onHandler_1">

I've seen this in other libraries, but I'm not sure how its implemented.  Maybe I'm searching for an example using the wrong key terms, but I can't find any reference.
The event itself is defined:
defineEmits({
  'someEvent': null
})

Not sure how you get the dot notation.

This sounds like XY problem. Consider explaining what you want to achieve with this.

@Estus Flask - The idea is just encapsulate a collection of related events more cleanly.  For example, someEvent could be a feature of a component (like a header bar or something)  and the customMember could be an event that happens to that compenent.  I see this pattern in the Veutify library, is why I'm asking.

Please clarify what you are referring to in Vuetify. The question isn't specific enough with respect to "seen this in other libraries".

You cannot create a custom modifier (not member), but you can mock the behavior that you want based on some data emitted by event payload :
<script setup >
const emit = defineEmits({
  someEvent(payload) {
   
  }
})
</script>

in parent  :

<script setup >

function handler_1(payload){
  //use payload to mock the behavior
}

</script>
<MyComponent @someEvent="onHandler_1">


It's not possible but you can emulate this by using dynamic event names in a functional component (I guess there's some way to do it in a regular component, probably wrapped into a functional one):
See on Vue SFC Playground
<script setup>            

import Comp from './Comp';

function onEvent(mod){
  alert(mod); // mod should be 'custom'
}
</script>

<template>
  <comp @event-custom="onEvent"/>
</template>

import { h } from "vue";

export default function Comp(props, {emit}){
  return h('button', {onClick(){
    for(const k in props){
      if(k.startsWith('onEvent')){
        const mod = k.slice('onEvent'.length).toLowerCase();
        emit('event-' + mod, mod);
      }
    }
  }}, 'Emit');
}

Another way to emulate the pattern (you can actually pass any data here, in an array also, not only a string):
See on Vue SFC Playground
<script setup>

import Comp from './Comp.vue';

function onEvent(mod){
  alert(mod); // mod should be 'custom'
}
</script>

<template>
  <comp @event="{custom: onEvent}"/>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  onEvent: Function
});

const handle = () => {
  const [mod, fn] = Object.entries(props.onEvent())[0];
  fn(mod);
}
</script>
<template>
  <button @click="handle">Emit</button>
</template>

